# Testing DataField to accept only data in past. Clean(), Django, AssertionError

Tags: python, django, data-cleaning, modelform, datefield

I am trying to write the test to check if my DataField accepts only data in the past but It doesn't work properly.

forms.py

```
class BookForm(PermissionRequiredMixin, ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'summary', 'tag', 'genre', 'language', 'book_format', 'read_date']

    def clean_read_date(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['read_date']
        #Check date is not in future.
        if data > datetime.date.today():
            raise ValidationError('Invalid date - book read date in future!')
        return data
```

test._forms.py

```
class BookFormTest(TestCase):
    def test_book_form_date_in_futuret(self):
        date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
        form_data = {'read_date': date}
        form = BookForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

Does anyone know why my clean_read_data doesn't work?
I know that probably I can do that in different ways but I read that using clean() is the best way to check that DateField is in future or in the past.

Comment: You should provide other required fields to make form valid. Also note `PermissionRequiredMixin`is using with view class, not form.

Comment: You can test whether or not that specific field is valid by checking if `form.errors` contains a 'read_date' key.

Comment: check if 'data' and 'datetime.date.today()' has same class.